# Android - Test Using Default strings.xml

Tags: android, gradle, testing, localization

Our Android package has a default `/res/values/strings.xml` and localized versions of the file in `res/values-XX/strings.xml` e.g. `/res/values-en/strings.xml`. Our unit tests seem to be running against the `en-US` locale, confirmed by getting the locale during a running unit test debug session.

How can we run our unit tests against the default `/res/values/strings.xml` file instead of one of the localized ones? Some setting in build.gradle?

Answer (score 0):

Its based on the locale of the device.  So if your device is in en-US it will use en-US strings when available.  The easiest way to force it to default is to pick some locale you don't have a strings file for, swap the device to that locale, and then launch the app.

Also your unit tests shouldn't be running any UI, and shouldn't be accessing Context in any way.  I assume you mean the UI or integration tests.  In which case the answer is the same-  set the locale of the device/emulator you run it on.